# API to get FB Developer App info (Photos Created count)?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a developer for an android app that uploads images to Facebook.  When I log into my FB developer console, I can see a counts of "photos created" on the bottom of the "Overview" page (in date range selected and per day). I can also see this information on "Insight" -> "Other Features" -> "Photos".

I am wondering if this information is able to be retrieved via an API so I could use it to automate report generation and/or show on a website the usage stats about my app?  A way to ask FB for "photos created" by my app?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it gives you the required information or not but Facebook Insight API might help you

Comment: looks like that's exactly what i needed!!! thanks!!  all my searching before wasn't getting me there...

Comment: well, that is exactly what i need, but using the Graph API explorer to try to get insight data isn't very helpful.  I compare the insight data for my app with the Graffiti example they use and mine doesn't have any "application_active_users", although from my FB Dev App console, it shows me the numbers and graphs for this data... can anyone help me understand why it isn't being returned in the Graph API explorer?